# Page.IsPostback Behaving weirdly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms

Though Form is Submitted the Page.IsPostback value returns false. 
This happens intermittently. 
   After studying the results of log we could only come to a conclusion that IsPostback is behaving weirdly however we couldn't figure out the actual cause why is it doing so.

What is the possibility of this weird behavior from IsPostback

1. Load Balancer Application Environment?
2. Use of third party Libraries corrupting the value of postback?
3. Any other Reasons which u can think off

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? What did you find that caused it?

Answer (score 0):

Log in every event of the request page lifecycle if there is a change on IsPostBack values. Ensure that every postback request is a POST or that there isn't any redirect before checking. Enable Trace if you need.